# ggplot facet_nested remove sub-headers and only keep the grouped headers

Tags: r, ggplot2, nested, facet-wrap, facet-grid

I have the following code that creates a plot with sub-headers.

```
pdf <- data.frame(xx = as.factor(c(rep(0, 100), rep(1, 100))),
                  value = rnorm(200),
                  selected_site = c('y', rep('n', 98), 'y'),
                  name = as.factor(rep(1:5, each = 20)),
                  version = rep(c('A', 'B'), each = 100))


pdf %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value, fill = xx)) +
  geom_histogram(alpha=0.6, position="identity") +
  facet_nested(version*selected_site ~ name, scale = 'free', ) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = '', values = c('red', 'blue')) +
  facetted_pos_scales(
    y = list(selected_site == TRUE ~ scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,2), guide = "none"),
             selected_site == FALSE ~ scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,15), guide = "none"))) +
  xlab('') + ylab('') +
  theme_bw() + theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

[image: facet_nested]

I would like to remove the subheaders "n" and "y" and only keep the grouped headers "A" and "B". Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Adapting my answer on [facet_wrap2() group by two variables, but label with one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77132658/facet-wrap2-group-by-two-variables-but-label-with-one/77132811#77132811) you could remove the strip background and text via the `strip` argument of `strip_nested`. This is however not perfect as it keeps some empty space. Unfortunately But I haven't found an option to get rid of that too:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

set.seed(123)

pdf |>
  ggplot(aes(x = value, fill = xx)) +
  geom_histogram(alpha = 0.6, position = "identity") +
  facet_nested(version * selected_site ~ name,
    scale = "free",
    strip = strip_nested(
      by_layer_y = TRUE,
      background_y = list(
        element_rect(),
        element_blank()
      ),
      text_y = list(
        element_text(),
        element_blank()
      )
    )
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "", values = c("red", "blue")) +
  facetted_pos_scales(
    y = list(
      selected_site == "TRUE" ~ scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 2), guide = "none"),
      selected_site == "FALSE" ~ scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 15), guide = "none")
    )
  ) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]